# JSON configuration properties containing dashes/hyphens in .NET Core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.0 project using a JSON configuration file, via the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` provider.

This application is a utility application to support another application that I do not control.
To keep consistency with that other application's configuration file format/style, multi-word setting keys use dashes between words.

Example JSON:

```json
{
    "multi-word-setting": "setting value"
}
```

Example settings class:

```cs
public class AppSettings
{
    // Pascal casing, as is typical in C#
    public string MultiWordSetting { get; set; }
}
```

Example application code:

```cs
class Program
{
    private static void Main ( string[ ] args )
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder( ).SetBasePath( Environment.CurrentDirectory ).AddJsonFile( "my-settings.json", true, true );
        IConfigurationRoot configRoot = configBuilder.Build( );
        AppSettings config = new AppSettings( );
        configRoot.Bind( config );
        Console.WriteLine( config.MultiWordSetting );
    }
}
```

However, given that hyphens are illegal in identifiers in C#, how can I follow typical C# naming conventions while also following the defined style of the application I am supporting?

I know I can use Newtonsoft and its `JsonPropertyAttribute` to just manually deal with the json data, but I'd prefer to make this work without "external" libraries, if possible. Besides, JSON.Net is over 20x larger, and the configuration libraries handle other stuff, such as automatic reloading, binding, merging, and optional files.

I've tried adding DataMember attributes to the properties of my class, to indicate the name of the json property, but that doesn't do the trick.

Is there a way to do this, with the .NET Core `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` provider?

Comment: Of note dashes aren't allowed in application settings names (according to Azure).  Which makes sense because they violate the established naming conventions.

Comment: Not everyone uses Azure. I have appsettings I need to store to match PCF naming conventions (which use dashes) and the deserialization simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was writing the question, I decided to dive into the .net core source and found that no, it is not possible to do what I wanted to do.

So, I decided to fix it and, pending the outcome of [ASP.Net Configuration Pull Request 775](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/pull/775), it may be possible in a future version of .net core. Please feel free to review/scrutinize that pull request.

Until then, a relatively simple workaround is to bind the configuration as normal and then manually access any unsupported settings via the ConfigurationRoot object's indexer.

Note that, if you're using the automatic reload feature, you'd have to manually handle setting the property on reload, too.